# Panel Data in Pandas, 'pivot_table', specifically

Tags: pandas, charts, pivot, panel, rows

Having a little trouble with the pivot_table command on this one.

My data looks like this; where AR1, AR2 etc. are the bank names; ta is the
variable name (there are more variable names in the 'wanted' format of the data.

```
Years Banks         AR1       AR2         AR3         AR4         AR5        AR6
2014    ta  11218331.43 113372.5    229236.19   277755.58   642079.91   65969.45
2013    ta  10887616.78 194139.35   215843.71   252022.75   621565.88   74034.76
2012    ta  10880829    216067.78   192874.64   282135.57   685483.88   74520.21
2011    ta  10716806.77 268230.63   224719.89   317973.86   760247.44   84360.41
```

I want the data to look like this (Don't focus on the actual data it is not the same just trying to illustrate the layout I would like):

```
Banks   Years            ta         bmg          c5  cfl       cir          cpi
AR1      2011   56.39506533 7.986790915 0.835297481 2.87    68.473  94.64298855
AR1      2012   50.09000362 0.641437575 0.844910056 5.12    69.752  100
AR1      2013   48.91334556 6.68353198  0.850272033 5.79    63.268  104.8830125
AR1      2014   55.07712922 20.46143223 0.853919746 10.66   62.07   77.37321888
AR2      2011   56.02560646 17.45613589 0.843308616 8.21    65.143  87.75930176
AR2      2012   56.39506533 7.986790915 0.835297481 2.87    68.656  94.64298855
```

Answer (score 0):

i have slightly extended your data set - added `bmg, c5, cir, cpi` values, so that it will look like your expected output table.

**Solution:**

```
(pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Years','Banks'], var_name='Bank')
   .pivot_table(index=['Bank','Years'], columns='Banks',
                values='value', fill_value=0, aggfunc='sum')
   .reset_index()
)
```

data set:

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]:
    Years Banks          AR1        AR2        AR3        AR4        AR5       AR6
0    2014    ta  11218331.43  113372.50  229236.19  277755.58  642079.91  65969.45
1    2014   bmg  11218331.43  113372.50  229236.19  277755.58  642079.91  65969.45
2    2014    c5  11218331.43  113372.50  229236.19  277755.58  642079.91  65969.45
3    2014   cir  11218331.43  113372.50  229236.19  277755.58  642079.91  65969.45
4    2013   bmg  10887616.78  194139.35  215843.71  252022.75  621565.88  74034.76
5    2013    ta  10887616.78  194139.35  215843.71  252022.75  621565.88  74034.76
6    2013   cpi  10887616.78  194139.35  215843.71  252022.75  621565.88  74034.76
7    2012    c5  10880829.00  216067.78  192874.64  282135.57  685483.88  74520.21
8    2012    ta  10880829.00  216067.78  192874.64  282135.57  685483.88  74520.21
9    2011    ta  10716806.77  268230.63  224719.89  317973.86  760247.44  84360.41
10   2011   cpi  10716806.77  268230.63  224719.89  317973.86  760247.44  84360.41
```

Melted (first 10 rows):

```
In [32]: pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Years','Banks'], var_name='Bank').head(10)
Out[32]:
   Years Banks Bank        value
0   2014    ta  AR1  11218331.43
1   2014   bmg  AR1  11218331.43
2   2014    c5  AR1  11218331.43
3   2014   cir  AR1  11218331.43
4   2013   bmg  AR1  10887616.78
5   2013    ta  AR1  10887616.78
6   2013   cpi  AR1  10887616.78
7   2012    c5  AR1  10880829.00
8   2012    ta  AR1  10880829.00
9   2011    ta  AR1  10716806.77
```

Pivot:

```
In [33]: (pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Years','Banks'], var_name='Bank')
   ....:    .pivot_table(index=['Bank','Years'], columns='Banks',
   ....:                 values='value', fill_value=0, aggfunc='sum')
   ....:    .reset_index()
   ....: )
Out[33]:
Banks Bank  Years       bmg        c5       cir       cpi        ta
0      AR1   2011         0         0         0  10716807  10716807
1      AR1   2012         0  10880829         0         0  10880829
2      AR1   2013  10887617         0         0  10887617  10887617
3      AR1   2014  11218331  11218331  11218331         0  11218331
4      AR2   2011         0         0         0    268231    268231
5      AR2   2012         0    216068         0         0    216068
6      AR2   2013    194139         0         0    194139    194139
7      AR2   2014    113372    113372    113372         0    113372
8      AR3   2011         0         0         0    224720    224720
9      AR3   2012         0    192875         0         0    192875
10     AR3   2013    215844         0         0    215844    215844
11     AR3   2014    229236    229236    229236         0    229236
12     AR4   2011         0         0         0    317974    317974
13     AR4   2012         0    282136         0         0    282136
14     AR4   2013    252023         0         0    252023    252023
15     AR4   2014    277756    277756    277756         0    277756
16     AR5   2011         0         0         0    760247    760247
17     AR5   2012         0    685484         0         0    685484
18     AR5   2013    621566         0         0    621566    621566
19     AR5   2014    642080    642080    642080         0    642080
20     AR6   2011         0         0         0     84360     84360
21     AR6   2012         0     74520         0         0     74520
22     AR6   2013     74035         0         0     74035     74035
23     AR6   2014     65969     65969     65969         0     65969
```

Comment: This looks great. But when I try to melt the data:                                    pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Years','Banks'], var_name='Bank').head(10)                          I get KeyError: 'Banks'

Comment: @StringTheo, what is the output of `df.columns.tolist()`?

Comment: df.columns.tolist()
[Years, Banks , AR1, AR2, AR3, AR4, AR5, AR6, AR7, AR8, AR10, AR11, AR12, AR13, AR15, AR16, etc. etc.

Comment: @StringTheo, can you post it as it is, including quotes? I guess you have trailing space in the `Banks ` column

Comment: I see it. Let me rename the column and see if that works.

Comment: Awesome, had to finagle with the values argument but good otherwise.

Comment: There is scant information on panel manipulation like this in pandas.